# Adding and Removing Methods from an Action passed as an argument in C#"

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add a method to an Action passed as an argument and remove it after the Action is triggered, but it seems it is creating a new value.

```
Action testAction = () => { Console.WriteLine("initial call"); };
damage.AddModifier(type, value, testAction);
testAction?.Invoke(); // only logs initial call
```

```
public void AddModifier(ModType type, float value, Action removeModEvent)
{
    AddModifier(type, value);
    
    Action e = null;
    e = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("remove modifier");
        RemoveModifier(type, value);
        removeModEvent -= e;
    };
    removeModEvent += e;
}
```

I worked around for a couple of hours but didn't find a solution, any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What **actual** problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a class that add and remove modifiers to a base value, I want to add an option to add a modifier and send an Action that when triggered, it auto removes the added modifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I concluded that there is no "correct" way to do this, so I decided to make a simple system to achieve the desired behavior.

I created a class that receives the action to be listened and the action to be triggered only once:

```
public class ActionTrack
{
        Action onTriggered;
    
        bool triggered = false;
    
        public ActionTrack(ref Action action, Action onTriggered)
        {
            this.onTriggered = onTriggered;
            action += OnTriggered;
        }
    
        void OnTriggered()
        {
            if (triggered) return;
            triggered = true;
    
            onTriggered?.Invoke();
        }
}
```

So to use it would be like this:

```
public void AddModifier(ModType type, float value, ref Action removeModEvent)
{
        AddModifier(type, value);

        new ActionTrack(ref removeModEvent, () =>
        {
            RemoveModifier(type, value);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the magic `ref` keyword, so that implicitly newly created Delegate is assigned to caller site variable:

```
Action testAction = () => Console.WriteLine("initial call");
testAction?.Invoke(); // only logs "initial call";
damage.AddModifier(type, value, ref testAction);
testAction?.Invoke(); // now also logs "remove modifier"


public void AddModifier(ModType type, float value, ref Action removeModEvent) {
   //...stuff, simplified version
   Action e = () => Console.WriteLine("remove modifier");
   removeModEvent += e;
}
```

Comment: I tried, the problem is that I need to unsubscribe after the call, but I cannot unsubscribe actions from it in a local function: 
Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'removeModEvent' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function Roslyn(CS1628)